# Replace index on some items in SQL table (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: mysql

I'm sure this is a bit dumb, but I'm very very beginner in MySQL so here I go.

I have a table Items with id (primary key), category_id (index) and some more columns. One of the categories (category_id = 5) is not needed anymore, and I would like to remove it and make all the items in category_id = 5 to become category_id = 7.

Find and replace won't give the possibility of altering keys, so I'm not sure about how to proceed with that.

*I can go to category_id and remove the number 5, but then all the items that used to have category_id = 5 will become null, right?*

Comment: Not with you if you update an index value the index will change and it's mysqls job to do that, but mysql will not change and queries that use code 5 (that's your job)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not sure about your explanation, but if all what you need is moving all items from category 5 to 7 you can use next simple query:

```
UPDATE items SET category_id = 7 WHERE category_id = 5;
```

[sql online editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/789474ad711f4063c33a4085ed6505d0/)

Answer (score -1):

You should not do this. Changing the index numbers will affect the referential integrity of your other tables and is not a great idea in general as a result. Even if you manually change the values, it's a bad practice and your database can scale enough to increase the index values rather than needing to compress them manually.

If you insist on doing this, you can use phpMyAdmin's search and replace feature to find and change the values in each table. I'm not sure what you mean by saying that find and replace won't change the keys, you'll just have to search through each table that could include the key and update it through phpMyAdmin.

Comment: The first part of this comment is OK, But doing "search and replace" in phpMyAdmin .  Could you not tell to do `UPDATE mytable SET category_id =7 WHERE category_id =5` ? That would be a good MySQL solution!

Comment: @Luuk since the poster is using phpMyAdmin and specifically mentioned that in the question and tags, I thought that would be a good solution. Rather than taking responsibility for describing how to find each table that could be affected and helping them write a query for each table, the graphical solution seems simplest to me. Sure, it can be done in pure SQL, but to me that seems to be making it more complicated than it needs to be.